# jQuery ajax post current date time ASP.NET web API

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API endpoint where I can POST some data.

Let's say I will post the following:

```
var myObject = {
name: "Jhon Smith",
age: "34",
accountCreated: "CURRENT DATE TIME"
};
```

what is the equivalent of `DateTime.Now` in JavaScript so I can assign the current date and time to `accountCreated`?

How can I parse this date (javascript current date time) into a C# DateTime object (in ASP.NET)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new Date()`  is the equivalent of `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 1):

Just  :

```
new Date().getTime();
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I did use it and the result parsed in ASP.NET is {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to `DateTime.Now` in JS would be `new Date()`. I wouldn't be relying on that sort of information from the client anyway as that isn't *really* the created date.

To ensure consistency with your dates it's best to leave that sort of stuff to the server where you can be sure that the `DateTime` used is in fact the true `DateTime` of when the record was created.